# Are there (free) alternatives to OS X task switching mechanism?

Tags: macos, alt-tab

I find OS X task switching very annoying. Specially while using spaces.

I'd like to be able to switch between windows regardless the app it belongs to, just like in Linux or Windows environments. I'd like the list of windows to be restricted to the space I'm current in. I'd like it also to include minimized windows. I've tried Witch but it would miss chrome so I gave it up. More recently I found out it is not free anymore.

Comment: How is this programming related?

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to be able to switch between windows regardless the app it belongs to, just like in Linux or Windows environments. I'd like the list of windows to be restricted to the space I'm current in. I'd like it also to include minimized windows.

You can do all of this with Exposé; the All Windows function will limit itself to a space, and will include minimized windows.

Comment: Excluding non-minimized windows of hidden applications, though

Comment: True, but with Spaces, who uses hiding anymore? ...Well, probably a lot of people, but personally I found myself just never hiding applications once I had Spaces for a while.

Comment: I want to navigate with the keyboard.